# Give users of group all permissions to a folder

Tags: permissions, users, groups

I have a folder which I want members of a group to be able to read, write, and execute in. I made a group named "potteryclass", and made it the group for the folder. I've added users "john" and "bob" to it. Here's how it looks:

```
$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x 2 john potteryclass 4096 Dec  4 04:22 projects

$ getent group potteryclass
potteryclass:x:1002:john,bob
```

This is how I did it:

```
sudo addgroup potteryclass
sudo usermod -a -G potteryclass john
sudo usermod -a -G potteryclass bob
sudo chown -R :potteryclass /home/projects
```

but user "bob" still cannot create new files in there.

What did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried logging off the user and then logging back on? This is often required after modifying group settings.

Comment: Ha, ugh that was it - after a restart it works - can you add your comment as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Answer added. I'm glad that's all it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've added a user to a group (whether it be an existing or new group), you must log that user off and log back on again for the group change to be applied.